# XML validation Cannot Resolve The Name

Tags: xml, xsd

I have never really worked with XML. Trying to validate a document

When validating the below this error is returned? What does it mean?

> Src-resolve: Cannot Resolve The Name 'kontekst:HovedOplysninger' To
> A(n) 'element Declaration' Component.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urn:VirksomhedKalenderHent_I xmlns:urn="urn:oio:skat:nemvirksomhed:ws:1.0.0"
                              xmlns:ns="http://rep.oio.dk/skat.dk/basis/kontekst/xml/schemas/2006/09/01/"
                              xmlns:ns1="http://rep.oio.dk/skat.dk/motor/class/virksomhed/xml/schemas/20080401/"
                              xmlns:urn1="urn:oio:skat:nemvirksomhed:1.0.0">
    <ns:HovedOplysninger>
        <ns:TransaktionIdentifikator>33593B0D-E7CF-40A2-AE76-530B72DE6AE3</ns:TransaktionIdentifikator>
        <ns:TransaktionTid>2017-04-24T12:00:00.146+02:00</ns:TransaktionTid>
    </ns:HovedOplysninger>
    <ns1:VirksomhedSENummerIdentifikator>12345678</ns1:VirksomhedSENummerIdentifikator>
    <urn1:AngivelseTypeNavn>qwerty</urn1:AngivelseTypeNavn>
    <urn:AngivelseBetalingFristHentFra>
        <urn1:SoegeDatoFraDate>2017-01-01</urn1:SoegeDatoFraDate>
        <urn1:SoegeDatoTilDate>2017-03-31</urn1:SoegeDatoTilDate>
    </urn:AngivelseBetalingFristHentFra>
</urn:VirksomhedKalenderHent_I>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:nemvirksomhedws="urn:oio:skat:nemvirksomhed:ws:1.0.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="urn:oio:skat:nemvirksomhed:ws:1.0.0"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           version="1.0" xmlns:nemvirksomhed="urn:oio:skat:nemvirksomhed:1.0.0"
           xmlns:virksomhed="http://rep.oio.dk/skat.dk/motor/class/virksomhed/xml/schemas/20080401/"
           xmlns:kontekst="http://rep.oio.dk/skat.dk/basis/kontekst/xml/schemas/2006/09/01/"
           xml:lang="DA">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation/>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:import namespace="http://rep.oio.dk/skat.dk/basis/kontekst/xml/schemas/2006/09/01/"
               schemaLocation="../../../../../../skat_dk/basis/kontekst/xml/schemas/2006/09/01/HovedOplysninger.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="urn:oio:skat:nemvirksomhed:1.0.0"
               schemaLocation="../../1_0_0/SoegeDatoTilDate.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="urn:oio:skat:nemvirksomhed:1.0.0"
               schemaLocation="../../1_0_0/SoegeDatoFraDate.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://rep.oio.dk/skat.dk/motor/class/virksomhed/xml/schemas/20080401/"
               schemaLocation="../../../../../../skat_dk/motor/class/virksomhed/xml/schemas/20080401/VirksomhedSENummerIdentifikator.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="urn:oio:skat:nemvirksomhed:1.0.0"
               schemaLocation="../../1_0_0/AngivelseTypeNavn.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="VirksomhedKalenderHent_I"
                type="nemvirksomhedws:VirksomhedKalenderHent_IType">
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="VirksomhedKalenderHent_IType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="kontekst:HovedOplysninger"/>
            <xs:element ref="virksomhed:VirksomhedSENummerIdentifikator"/>
            <xs:element ref="nemvirksomhed:AngivelseTypeNavn"/>
            <xs:element name="AngivelseBetalingFristHentFra">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="nemvirksomhed:SoegeDatoFraDate"
                                    minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element ref="nemvirksomhed:SoegeDatoTilDate"
                                    minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Your master XSD is importing multiple additional XSDs. Please edit your question and add them.

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSD(s) that tries to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

The XSD has a namespace declaration

```
xmlns:kontekst="http://rep.oio.dk/skat.dk/basis/kontekst/xml/schemas/2006/09/01/"
```

and it has an `xs:import` for that namespace -- so that's a good start.

You haven't shown us the schema document that's being imported, and my guess (from the error message) is that it doesn't contain an element declaration for the name `HovedOplysninger`.

When you solve that problem you'll need to tackle the references to elements in namespaces `virksomhed` and `nemvirksomhed` which don't appear to be imported at all.